# Are names that can be confused with the site name allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking about names like [super user](https://superuser.com/users/60459/super-user), [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/68227/superuser) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/77223/superuser).

Comment: At least ♦ is not valid as part of a user name.

Comment: But then again, which new user really knows what the ♦ means? Even the FAQ doesn't mention it.

Comment: How about a slightly different question - "Does anyone care if user names can be confused with the site name?" - My answer: "Me no carey"

Comment: @slhck Any new user reading the about page will quickly learn what the diamond means. We also usually introduce ourselves quickly if we need to intervene.

Comment: @Diago I know, but not always. I've often had users thinking I was a mod/admin because I edited their post.

Comment: @slhck. You are a moderator. The reputation system is working since you received the ability to do that. That's 100% correct. Diamond moderators are enforcers, but, we still abide by the community. We are not one law to rule them all. We've often had to reverse decisions because the community wanted them reversed, but personally did not agree with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange engine doesn't enforce unique names and this shouldn't extend to us having to "protect" arbitrary names from re-use *except* where impersonation is occurring.

"Impersonation" varies, but *in this case* I'd be looking for a pretence that they are a moderator or affiliated with the site - this could include what they post, comment, say in chat and/or the content of their gravatar (if, for example, they used the SU icon).

I don't think there's currently a cause for concern.

Comment: Also note none of these are even active users...

Comment: @simon yeah, I removed the dead users so there's at least less possibility of confusion. One of them is active.